Why '-pedantic-errors' flag/switch is not catching that I'm using __attribute__ in C++?
I have a question, I'm using C++ and GNU g++ with the next characteristics
g++ main.cpp -std=c++17 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -o main

And im using
__attribute__((unused))
And my code is the one shown below:
int main(){
    __attribute__((unused)) int x=0;
}

I know that I can use [[maybe__unused]] to 'be ISO compliant', but I wanted to try the -pedantic-errors switch because I have never try it before
I expected to see an error that tells me that I'm using a gnu gcc/g++ extension, but the code compiles without any error
Why is '-pedantic-errors' switch not working?

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html :
-Wpedantic does not cause warning messages for use of the alternate keywords whose names begin and end with ‘__’.

It is.   In the link that Pepijn gave, it is documented that -Wpedantic does not cause warning messages for the alternate keywords you are using.   It also goes on to state that those "escape routes" are intended only for use in system headers, and that application programs (i.e. user code) should not use them.   Doing this is not even at odds with the intent to give diagnostics for code that does not comply with standards, since the standard itself reserves such identifers (e.g. starting with two underscores) for use by the implementation

@Peter The "escape routes ... only for use in system headers" part apparently only applies to __intN__ and __extension__ extensions. Some other extensions are unavoidable.

Ok! i just read the info, thanks to all of you! but so, according with the words of @HolyBlackCat, if im using a standard pre c++17 can i still use attribute((unused)) or my only option if i wanna be 'ISO compliant' and be able to avoid warnings of unused variables (just in case i need to) is to use void cast ?

The abstract "ISO compliance" shouldn't be a goal (any non-trivial program will use non-standard extensions), but make sure all compilers you want to support have this attribute. E.g. MSVC doesn't.

Thanks budy, thanks to all for your answers!

Well using __xyz__  symbols should only be used internally by the compiler and/or standard library code. Using them yourself will make it likely your code will not compile on other compilers (e.g. your code would fail on msvc compiler anyway).  So better to make a header file that has a #define ATTR_UNUSED __attribute__(unused)__ which you can conditionally compile to something else for a different compiler.  And then you can type ATTR_UNUSED int x=0; or something like that.

Thanks Pepjin i didnt know that i shouldnt use ___xyz__symbols in user code, i guess [[maybe__unused]] is the way
